# How do I fix this Unexpected token error?

Tags: javascript, json, error-handling

Getting an error and I don't know why. Any idea?

`Unexpected token / in JSON at position 233`

I have found a few possible fixes and implemented them but they have not worked either.

This is the code:

```js
const v2_ABIs = require("./Uniswap_V2_ABIs.json");

const v2abi = JSON.parse(v2_ABIs);

v2abi = v2abi.trim();

console.log(v2abi);
```

Comment: The error message points to position 223 in the string. Without seeing the JSON and what is around that position, we cannot really tell you much more.

Comment: Use jsonlint.com to check the syntax of the JSON file.

Comment: Just tried jsonlint.com and it says it is a valid json however my code still isn't compiling

Comment: Turns out the answer was to remove JSON.parse(). Thank you guys for trying to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a read through the comments. If removing JSON.parse stopped causing the error. That means the JSON you where using contained something that caused a js exception when trying to parse it. If you can share the JSON I can pinpoint the exact issue, but if you don't actually need to parse it then its no problem.